# My Find Ladders solution is unable to update the list representing the path to the current node

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

**This is the problem description:**

> Given two words (beginWord and endWord), and a dictionary's word list,
> find all shortest transformation sequence(s) from beginWord to
> endWord, such that:
>
> Only one letter can be changed at a time Each transformed word must
> exist in the word list. Note that beginWord is not a transformed word.
>
> Note:
>
> Return an empty list if there is no such transformation sequence. All
> words have the same length. All words contain only lowercase
> alphabetic characters. You may assume no duplicates in the word list.
> You may assume beginWord and endWord are non-empty and are not the
> same.

**Test case:**

```
Input:
beginWord = "hit",
endWord = "cog",
wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]

Output:
[
  ["hit","hot","dot","dog","cog"],
  ["hit","hot","lot","log","cog"]
]
```

**My issue:**

To keep track of the path that the traversal takes to get to the current node, I'm trying to pass in a path array that is updated every time a new node is added to the queue. Currently, the code that updates the path is: `q.append((word, level + 1, previous + [top]))`. For some reason, my path array isn't actually updating every time. What did I do wrong?

**My code:**

```
import collections
class Solution:
    def findLadders(self, beginWord: str, endWord: str, wordList: List[str]) -> List[List[str]]:
        representations = {}
        for word in wordList:
            for i in range(len(word)):
                rep = word[:i] + "_" + word[i+1:]
                if word[:i] + "_" + word[i+1:] in representations:
                    representations[rep].append(word)
                else:
                    representations[rep] = [word]
        q = collections.deque()
        q.append((beginWord, 0, []))
        shortest = 0
        result = []
        visited = {}
        while q:
            top, level, previous = q.popleft()
            if top in visited: continue
            if not found:
                if top == endWord:
                    found = True
                    result.append(path)
                    shortest = level
                else:
                    visited[top] = True
                    for i in range(len(top)):
                        rep = word[:i] + "_" + word[i+1:]
                        for word in representations[rep]:
                            q.append((word, level + 1, previous + [top]))
                        representations[rep] = []
            else:
                if top == endWord:
                    result.append(previous + [top])
        return result
```

Comment: what counts as a transformation? can letters be inserted or removed?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to look at the shortest distance algorithm - dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: A transformation is changing one letter. I know this can be solved with A*, but I'm trying to practice a faster to code solution (while maybe less efficient) for an interview

Comment: not A*, Dijkstra's algorithm serves the best in this case.

Answer (score 0):

this is solution in Dijkastra's algorithm. The first step is to build a graph. The second step is simply finding a path from start to end with the algorithm

```
import heapq

beginWord = "hit"
endWord = "cog"
wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]

class Node:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.children = []
        self.visited = False
        self.last = None

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        s += self.word + "\n"
        s += ",".join([c.word for c in self.children]) + "\n"
        s += str(self.visited) + "\n"
        return s

def buildGraph(begin, end, wordList):

    all_words = wordList + [begin, end]
    all_words = list(dict.fromkeys(all_words))
    d = { w : Node(w) for w in all_words }

    for i, w in enumerate(all_words):
        for w2 in (all_words[i+1:]):
            if canHop(w, w2):
                d[w].children.append(d[w2])
                d[w2].children.append(d[w])

    return d

def canHop(w, w2):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x == False, [c == w2[i] for i, c in enumerate(w)]  ))) == 1

graph = buildGraph(beginWord, endWord, wordList)

s = graph[beginWord]
e = graph[endWord]

def findLadders(s, e, graph):
    scores = []
    heapq.heapify(scores)

    s.visited = True
    paths = [s]
    heapq.heappush(scores, (0, s.word))

    flag = False

    while len(scores) > 0:
        d, w = heapq.heappop(scores)
        n = graph[w]
        for c in n.children:
            if c.visited:
                continue
            c.last = n
            if c == e:
                flag = True
                break
            c.visited = True
            heapq.heappush(scores, (d+1, c.word))
        if flag:
            break
    result = []
    last = e
    while last is not None:
        result.append(last.word)
        last = last.last
    return result

print(findLadders(s,e,graph))
```